# How can i get gauss-lobatto points on a quadrilateral?

Tags: finite-element, spectral-method

How can I get Gauss-Lobatto points on a quadrilateral or a triangle in $x$-$y$ plane?

I am only getting abscissa coordinates and weights by solving Lobatto polynomials using Lobatto quadrature. Please suggest a method to get the $x$-$y$ coordinates

Comment: What do you mean by Gauss-Lobatto points on a triangle?  What properties of Gauss-Lobatto do you wish to preserve?

Comment: the distance between points and number of points i get on sides of a quadrilateral should be same on the sides of a triangle as well...

Comment: i see.  if that's the only requirement, you can form the nodes a bunch of different ways.  One explicit way is in https://www.uea.ac.uk/~h007/publications/lobatto.pdf.  Others include Hesthaven and Teng's construction, or Warburton's Warp and Blend nodes.  Many of these are described in the Nodal DG Methods book @GoHokies mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For domains that are logically square or cubic (like your quadrilateral), you can use the *tensor product* (dimension-by-dimension) approach. That is, generate the 2D Gauss-Lobatto point *matrix* as the tensor product of your 1D Gauss-Lobatto point vectors.

An example: if your 1D Gauss-Lobatto points are $(x_1,x_2)$, then in 2D you get the following four points: $(x_i,x_j)_{i,j=1,2}$.

Generating the Gauss-Lobatto points on triangular domains is a bit more complicated. Fortunately, there are good references. Here's a couple to get the ball rolling:

1. The *Nodal DG methods* book by Hesthaven and Warburton, appendix A ([Google Books](https://books.google.it/books?id=APQkDOmwyksC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false))
2. The Matlab code from said book ([link](http://www.nudg.org/)).
3. [These](http://math2.uncc.edu/~shaodeng/TEACHING/math5172/Lectures/Lect_15.PDF) lecture notes on multidimensional Gaussian quadrature.